# How to decorate dynamic class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, decorator

I have class which I use as response type. This class can have any key which represents conversationId and value is last Message of this conversation.
And I need to decorate it for swagger. This is my simple class:

```js
import { Message } from "./message.dto";

export class LastConversationMessages{
    [conversationId: string]: Message;
  }
```

How can I use ApiProperty in this class? This doesn't work:

```js
import { Message } from "./message.dto";
import {ApiProperty} from "@nestjs/swagger";

export class LastConversationMessages{
    @ApiProperty({
        additionalProperties: {
            type: Message
        }
    })
    [conversationId: string]: Message;
  }
```

I throws error: Decorators are not valid here.

Comment: `[conversationId: string]` isn't a field but a type def, that's why you cannot use decorators over it.

Comment: I understand it why I can't use decorator, but how to document class like this?

Comment: [Probably a raw definition](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters#raw-definitions)